# Create a Folder Structure from User input

Tags: java, io

I have created a quick example below. I want to create a folder structure based on the text input of a user. eg:

text field 1 is: `2001`

text field 2 is: `test`

Then the folder structure is `c:\2001\test`

It's part of a bigger app but this is the bit that has me stuck.  Any help appreciated..

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.*;

public class CreateDirectory extends JFrame {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new CreateDirectory().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public CreateDirectory() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Create New Job App");

    panel pan = new panel();
    add(pan.panel);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}
}

class panel {

private JButton btn1 = new JButton("Create");
private JTextField txt1 = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField txt2 = new JTextField(10);

JPanel panel;

public panel() {
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(btn1);
    panel.add(txt1);
    panel.add(txt2);

    btn1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btn1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }

        private void btn1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            File files = new File("C:\\Directory2\\Sub2\\Sub-Sub2");
            if (!files.exists()) {
                if (files.mkdirs()) {

                } else {
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All what you need is to mentioned the directories to be created like this

```
  private void btn1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        File files = new File("c:\\"+txt1.getText()+"\\"+txt2.getText());
        if (!files.exists()) {
            if (files.mkdirs()) {

            } else {
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this could help!

Comment: Perfect,  Thanks very much, I was so close on a previous attempt. I was putting the txt1 without getText and it was returning the properties of the text field into my results.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have button , so on its action listener method, get values from both text boxes, validate them , then call a method something like this

```
private void createDirectories(String textInputOne , String textInputTwo){

    String root="";//Your base directory or Drive in your case c:/

    String totalPath=root+File.separator+textInputOne+File.separator+textInputTwo;

    File folder=new File(totalPath);
    if(!folder.exists()){
        folder.mkdirs();
    }else{

        System.out.println("already exists");
    }

}
```

I hope this works , and if you don't  have permission in your base folder/drive `mkdirs()` will return false.

check that too.